# ExcelFuzzyLookUp: Compare Cells In The Same Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, comparison

I'm trying to compare two cells that are in the same row and same table. I've been trying to use Fuzzy Lookup to provide a measure of similarity but what happens is that the cells move to match what I'm looking for. Instead of moving the cells, I want the cells on the left to be compared to the cell next to it.

If that didn't make sense above, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
| Source 1      | Source 2     | Similarity |                                                   |
|---------------|--------------|------------|---------------------------------------------------|
| Yellow Jumper | Yellow Shirt | 0.x        | (x being the similarity number e.g. 0.95 similar) |
```

But what happens is, cells below get mixed up so instead, it's Yellow Jumper being compared with a green jumper for example. How would I be able to achieve the thing above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fond of Fuzzy Lookup (FL) for the reason that what is disclosed about it indicates that the "similarity" provided as a measure for one to make decisions on is likely to be false precision so one makes a confident choice, but based on garbage — "Garbage In, Garbage Out" was coined for a good reason — so whether it is a valid choice is not really apparent to the decision.

However, that aside as much as possible (because you are being assaulted by a variation on that reservation), bear in mind FL is matching based upon whole cells, not portions only. So "yellow jumper" and "green jumper" match to whatever degree (maybe even whatever degree FL asserts) because both have "jumper" in them.

A solution for that particular issue is to add columns to your table/s (usually called "helper columns" in Excel) in which you attempt to "concentrate" the data you desire a match attempt for so FL only considers the part you consider important.

So, for instance, you might have a column with a formula consisting of a concatenation (or textjoining of an internal array) of one to several (to "many" I suppose) words you want to use for the matching. The formula might `SEARCH()` or `FIND()` for each one, one after the other (with concatenation of whatever kind between them) and if there is a match (the function used does NOT return an error), the word searched for would be added to the string. If not, not.

Seems like one could just make the string with all the words and save the trouble, but that will lower the match "similarity" in way that misleads you. The above would give a more valid "similarity." But for your purposes, it might not be needed and a simple full string might work adequately for you. Either way though, if, for example, "jumper" is NOT something you want matched for, not including it would achieve that.

One would need such a column for each column actively used in the FL. The reason for that should be apparent:  that "similarity" rating again. Looking only for "yellow" against an original column that only has it in phrases like "yellow jumper" will only match about 50% of the target generating a far lower "similarity" value and perhaps losing some matches for you if you list only those above some level.

On the other hand, the above is sort of creating your own FL, just using the AddIn for the final step rather than writing more formulas. Makes one wonder.